# Bothered by an unknown letter case name

Tags: naming, naming-standards, camelcase

This side question bothers me: Has_This_Case_A_Name?

---

Here is what I could find, but This_Case_Is_Missing:

```
+---------------------------------------+---------------+
|                 Names                 |    Example    |
+---------------------------------------+---------------+
| camelCase, lowerCamelCase             | thisIsACat    |
| UpperCamelCase, PascalCase, BumpyCase | ThisIsACat    |
+---------------------------------------+---------------+
| kebab-case, spinal-case, lisp-case    | this-is-a-cat |
| COBOL-CASE                            | THIS-IS-A-CAT |
| Train-Case                            | This-Is-A-Cat |
+---------------------------------------+---------------+
| snake_case                            | this_is_a_cat |
| SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE, MACRO_CASE      | THIS_IS_A_CAT |
| ???                                   | This_Is_A_Cat |
+---------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Sources:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Special_case_styles
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Multiple-word_identifiers
- http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CapitalizationRules

Comment: I've never heard of a name for the last case in 30 years of programming. But then I've also never heard of "snake case" or "train case".

Comment: Since most of those names are made up and not actually used by a majority of programmers, feel free to make up another.

Comment: Looking at the train case, you should call it the subway_case.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard, it's more a big snake case, so Dragon_Case.

Comment: Whilst you are at it, perhaps you could find/dream up a name for the unit test convention of using the form `ForSomeSetup_WithATransaction_TheResultShouldBe`, ie mixing `_` with PascalCase.

Comment: You could call it Trailer_Truck_Case /s

Comment: The wikipedia reference for kebab case seems to be circular. I would say casing refers only to the casing of the letters, not the space replacement. So its Title Case with underscores

Comment: Why all the downvotes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This case is used in the programming language ADA:

[WikiWand - Naming Convention # ADA](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Naming_convention_(programming)#/Ada)

This convention is known as `Mixed_Case_With_Underscores` or `Ada_Case`.